# Postgres fulltext index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

```
CREATE INDEX message_fulltext_idx ON feedback USING gin(to_tsvector(message));
```

```
ERROR:  functions in index predicate must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 28):

You need to include the optional config parameter.  Without it, the function is not immutable.  For example, if you want the standard English text parsing:

```
CREATE INDEX message_fulltext_idx ON feedback
  USING gin(to_tsvector('english', message));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The first form of `to_tsvector` will use a default for the config parameter that comes from the setting `default_text_search_config`.  Since that is a changable setting, the function is not immutable.  If it were to change, an existing index based on the non-mimmutable function would be silently corrupted.  So it's forbidden.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX.